# Fractional Part Inequality

Tags: number-theory, inequality

How can I show that the following inequality holds when $x$ and $y$ are coprime positive integers greater than 2, and $r$ is an arbitrary rational number greater than or equal to $2$?

$$\frac{(x-1)(y-1)}{6}\left(1-r\frac{x+y+1}{xy}\right)\leq\sum_{k=1}^x\sum_{l=1}^{\lfloor y(1-k/x)\rfloor}\{r(1-k/x-l/y)\}$$

Note: $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes fractional part.

Comment: b is meant to be y?

Comment: yes, fixed. thanks